# Groovy XmlSlurper get value of the node without children

Tags: groovy, html-parsing, nodes, xmlslurper

I'm parsing HTML and trying to value of a parent node itself, without values of the children nodes.

HTML example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
             <a href="http://intro.com">extra stuff</a>
             Text I would like to get.
             <a href="http://example.com">link to example</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
def tagsoupParser = new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()
def slurper = new XmlSlurper(tagsoupParser)
def htmlParsed = slurper.parseText(stringToParse)

println htmlParsed.body.div[0]
```

However above code returns:

> extra stuff Text I would like to get. link to example

How can I get only parent node value without children? Example:

> Text I would like to get.

P.S:
I tried removing extra elements by doing substring but it proves to be unreliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch to using `XmlParser` instead of `XmlSlurper`, you can do:

```
println htmlParsed.body.div[0].localText()[0]
```

Assuming you are [on Groovy 2.3+](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html#localText())

Comment: Tried and here is exception: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.localText()

Comment: Fair enough...thought it was Parser only :-)

Comment: I wish I could switch to Parser but everything is written using Slurper.

Comment: @Melr that looks like a Groovy version, not a Parser/Slurper issue...  What version of Groovy are you on?

Comment: @MeIr I *think* you can use this kind of workaround: `htmlParsed.body.div[0].nodeIterator().collect().find().@children.findAll { it instanceof String }.join()`  if you can't upgrade version...

Answer (score 1):

No need to switch to `XmlParser`, just cast the first `div` as `NodeChild`:

```
def html = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def text = (html.body.div.first() as NodeChild).localText().first()
```

```
// Using @CompileStatic:
GPathResult html = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
GPathResult div = html["body"]["div"]
String text = (div.first() as NodeChild).localText().first()
```